# Issue in Reading data from already created device under iio for st_lsm6dsox for step count

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, interrupt, iio, significant-motion-sensor

I have already enabled driver for st_lsm6dsox embedded features which created 9 devices with accel and gyro , magnetometer raw data along with step count and tilt detection features .I can read raw data from accel and gyro raw data but couldnt read step count and detect tilt and step detection those features [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqjuQ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wodZ.png). In events directory its empty , i tried sending 1 and 0 to hwfifo_flush but couldnt get any output
I tried changing attributes but in veil can you please help me to get data from the sensor devices for step count
code reference: Im using drivers provided by st link is this: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/st-mems-android-linux-drivers-iio/tree/master/drivers/iio/stm/imu/st_lsm6dsox

Also can you please mention whether i need to enable interrupts ,and how to configure events to get data any hardware connection changes?
Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not asking ST via their GH page then? Another approach is to use drivers in the vanilla kernel and see if you have any differences.

Comment: I did ask in st community but didn't get any response as of now  , vanilla kernel?

Comment: Vanilla kernel is the official one made by Torvalds. As of today, v6.4.y is available.

Comment: okay thanks now its detecting and gave me some directories like scan elements and buffer, still nothing to directly read step count and how can i detect events , when i check interrupt signal voltage on interrupt pin i guess its spiking to some voltage when ever i move a sensor but how to capture it from sysfs attribute name. how can i detect tilt detection, significant motion , step detection which are event based in their code